# Getting 504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu) in django nginx

Tags: django, nginx, digital-ocean

I am facing problems launching my django app in digitalocean. I have done all the needful but I am quite sure I made error some where.  Below is my nginx configuration file. What could be the problem . Thanks alot .
PLease I would also love to know how to access nginx error log file through command line.

```
server {

server_name server_Ip;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/username/myproject/smsdigo;
}

    location /media/ {
    root /home/username/myproject/smsdigo;
}

      location /locale/ {
    root /home/ebong/myproject/smsdigo;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
}


}
   server {

listen 80;

client_max_body_size 3000M;
client_body_buffer_size 3000M;
client_body_timeout 120;
```

}

Comment: sorry for this question, it might be silly, but have you changed `server_name server_Ip;` `on` your `real ip`?

Comment: No I am using the same server IP

Comment: you need to change `server_ip` to `real ip` for example `server_name 123.456.78.90;` or `server_name my_site.com;`

Answer (score 1):

Problably you need increase `fastcgi` timeout directives:
Try 60s or more. For example:

```
server{
  fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 60s;
}
```